# What's the difference between HttpContext.RequestAborted and CancellationToken parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, kestrel, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm trying to create an **async view component** for **ASP.NET Core 2.0**. It will do an action that should be cancelled when the user navigates away from the page. I've got the following options:

1. Using the HttpContext.RequestAborted
2. Using a CancellationToken parameter
3. I could also chain the tokens

Option 1 looks like this:

```
public class AmazingMessageViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string text, int wait)
    {
        //uses request aborted
        await Task.Delay(wait, HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        return View<string>(text);
    }
}
```

Option 2 looks like this:

```
public class AmazingMessageViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string text, int wait)
    {
        await Task.Delay(wait, cancellationToken);
        return View<string>(text);
    }
}
```

*Both action do not work with Kestrel* (looks like a bug). In both cases the tokens are filled (maybe because of struct?)

What is the difference and what should I use?

Comment: HttpContext.RequestAborted and injected CancellationToken should be the same, the source of the binder: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a5db01169af91bee3eca6ebfabf2b6b3d6c75539/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs#L29 (original thread: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5239#issuecomment-244924877). It does not work for me neither (at least when debugging).

Comment: Update: by debugging I mean IIS Express and also I am using Core 1.1. According to the thread it should work with Core 2.0 and Kestrel.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a 2 months old issue, but I have been struggling with this today too and came to some conclusions.

---

*What is the difference and what should I use?*

According to [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5239#issuecomment-244924877) these are exactly the same things. From [CancellationTokenModelBinder source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a5db01169af91bee3eca6ebfabf2b6b3d6c75539/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs#L29):

```
var model = (object)bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
```

I can confirm, I always get the same values from `HttpContext.RequestAborted` and `CancellationToken` injection.

Advantage of `HttpContext.RequestAborted` is that it is available in all controller's methods, not just actions. The `CancellationToken` parameter is IMHO better readable but if you have a number of nested methods that need to react to the token, it may become impractical to propagate it through their parameters. I would just use the one that better suits your needs.

---

From the same thread, [another post](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5239#issuecomment-298160907):

> This only works in 2.0 not in 1.x

I know, this is not your case but it was mine.

---

Finally, still from the same thread and especially discussion [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/#comment-3495363011), there's a [problem in IIS](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/38) (specifically in its interface with Kestrel). AFAIK you have to use Kestrel and optionally (mandatory for 1.x) a reverse proxy such as IIS, Apache or Nginx. I believe this is your case.

---

Some quick testing: I created a project from Web API template using ASP .NET Core 2.0 and modified the first action in the controller it created:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    Thread.Sleep(7000);
    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // breakpoint here
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Hit F5. It starts the app (including Kestrel) with IIS Express in front of it. Make the request and abort it (by closing a browser tab) before the 7 seconds. `cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested` is `false` when the breakpoint triggers.

Now, change the debug profile from IIS Express to WebApplication1 (or whatever it is called):

[image]

Everything works as expected for me.

I did also try the same with ASP .NET Core 1.1 but with no success.

---

AFAIK with ASP .NET Core 2.0, one should be able to use Kestrel on its own. I don't know if Apache or Nginx are doing better than IIS.

Comment: You are right. I was also facing this issue. After reading your answer, I tried without using IIS Express and it worked perfectly as expected.