# How to cancel .Net Core Web API request using Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following two applications

- Angular 6/7 App
- .Net Core Web API

I am making **GET** request to API using Angular's **HttpClient** as shown below

```
this.subscription = this.httpClient.get('api/Controller/LongRunningProcess')
                                   .subscribe((response) => 
                                   {
                                      // Handling response
                                   });
```

API controller's **LongRunningProcess** method has the following code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("LongRunningProcess")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LongRunningProcess(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // Dummy long operation
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    // Option 1 (Not working)
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;

                    // Option 2 (Not working)
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Thread.Sleep(6000);
                }

            }, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OperationCanceledException)} thrown with message: {e.Message}");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Now I want to cancel this long-running process so I am unsubscribing from client side as shown below

```
// On cancel button's click
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Above code will **cancel** the request and I can see it is canceled in the **Network** tab of the browser as shown below

[image]

But it is not going to make **IsCancellationRequested** to **true** in the method   **LongRunningProcess** of the API, so the operation will keep going.

**[Note]:** Both **Option 1** and **Option 2** in API method are not working even if I make a call using postman.

**Question:** Is there any way to cancel that **LongRunningProcess** method's operation?

Comment: May be there is an issue while using both Kestrel and IIS Express. I tried without using IIS Express (refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574061/httprequest-not-aborted-cancelled-on-browser-abort-in-asp-net-core-mvc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153525/whats-the-difference-between-httpcontext-requestaborted-and-cancellationtoken-p) and it worked perfectly as expected. I got IsCancellationRequested = true.

Comment: Any answer to this question? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I didn't check later on but if you read my previous comment that may help

Answer (score 1):

When angular cancel request, you can get cancellation token from  http context

```
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = HttpContext.RequestAborted;
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // The client has aborted the request
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need break in this case only use like this

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("LongRunningProcess")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> LongRunningProcess(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       // Dummy long operation
       await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(60000));
   }

    return Ok();
 }
```

You can read it more [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already went through the above blog and it also states that 'Instead the Task.Delay call throws a TaskCancelledException when it detects that the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property is true, immediately halting execution.' and even Microsoft docs say that method 'ThrowIfCancellationRequested' provides functionality equivalent to if (token.IsCancellationRequested)throw new OperationCanceledException(token);. But the issue is cancellation token is not able to detect that the request is canceled.

Comment: I will try again and will get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your dummy long operation does not monitor the canncellationToken. I'm not sure it is actually your intention to start 10 one-minute tasks all in parallel without any delay, which is what your code does.

In order to have a dummy long operation, the code would be like

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("LongRunningProcess")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LongRunningProcess(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Dummy long operation
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            }
        });

    return Ok();
}
```

`Task.Run` is just equivalent to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, by the way.

However, if you just need a dummy long-run operation in your web API, then you can also simply use `Task.Delay`, which supports cancellation token. `Task.Delay` throws an exception when the request is canceled, so add exception handling code when you need to do something after request cancellation.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("LongRunningProcess")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LongRunningProcess(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Dummy long operation
    await Task.Delay(60000, cancel);

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here in the question, I have not written code to pass cancellation token in any task. But in actual code I did and I put a breakpoint in a loop and then canceled the request from client-side and checked it. It didn't make 'IsCancellationRequested' to 'true'. Still, I will try again and get back to you.

Comment: I see, then the problem must be in your Angular code where you call `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`. how about attaching the code around that to your question?

Comment: I have already written a piece of code in the question. Only that much code is required to cancel any request as per my knowledge.

Comment: as I don't see any wrong in the client code you provided, so I just suspected something that you do in the rest of your client code. there would be something wrong. just as a possibility though

Comment: _Task.Run is just equivalent to Task.Factory.StartNew, by the way._. [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

Comment: @Advait Baxi, there's an interesting issue in angular's github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27411#issuecomment-444166771 . don't you have such a problem in your rxjs imports?

Comment: @Joelius the point of my answer is not that part, by the way. the code provided in the question initially had a code where it didn't check the cancellation token inside task run, which is like the code in Tony's answer. the answer is now updated, so it looks fine now. I'm guessing something wrong in client code rather than the server code.

Comment: @YasIkeda Even if I make a call using postman, it didn't work. It didn't update IsCancellationRequested to true. It didn't cancel the task.

Comment: I didn't criticize your answer, I just wanted to point out that the calls are not fully equal, mostly because you can't even call them with the same arguments. The cursive part was a citation of your answer. My comment was only about that part :) Let's stop hijacking the comments with this now.

Answer (score 0):

Any http observables still running at the time will complete and run their logic unless you unsubscribe in onDestroy(). Whether the consequences are trivial or not will depend upon what you do in the subscribe handler. If you try to update something that doesn't exist anymore you may get an error.

Tip: The Subscription contains a closed boolean property that may be useful in advanced cases. For HTTP this will be set when it completes. In Angular it might be useful in some situations to set a _isDestroyed property in ngDestroy which can be checked by your subscribe handler.

Tip 2: If handling multiple subscriptions you can create an ad-hoc new Subscription() object and add(...) any other subscriptions to it - so when you unsubscribe from the main one it will unsubscribe all the added subscriptions too.

So, best practice is to use takeUntil() and unsubscribe from http calls when the component is destroyed.

```
   import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
   .....
   ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.destroy$.next();  // trigger the unsubscribe
     this.destroy$.complete(); // finalize & clean up the subject stream
   }
```

Comment: Usually I do in the following way (the same way you are saying)

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

private unsubscriber = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnDestroy()
{
    if (this.unsubscriber)
    {
      this.unsubscriber.next();
      this.unsubscriber.complete();
    }
}

But in the above scenario (in a question) I want to cancel the request on a button so I took a subscription and did unsubscribe on a button's click.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cancellationToken = new CanellationToken();
    cancellationToken.CancelAfter(2000);
    using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("emp", 
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationTokenSource.Token))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var emp = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<empDto>>(stream, _options);
    }
```

Further we can also have this "CancellationToken" class, which is nothing much Http client method which terminates the request after certain time-interval.

Answer (score 0):

1. - In angular  subscription.unsubscribe(); closes the channel and causes CORE to cancel the API caller's thread, that's good.
2. - Don't use await Task.Run(()... This creates a result/task that should be disposed, if not, the task keeps going, your pattern doesn't permit this - that's why it continues to run.
3. - Simply - 'await this.YourLongRunningFunction()', I'm pretty sure that when the owning thread throws the OperationCancelled exception your task will end.
4. If "3" doesn't work, then pass a cancellation token to your long running task and set that when you catch your OperationCancelled exception.