# Http request doesn't get canceled via angular app

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, httprequest, cancellation-token

When we are hitting a button on our angualr app a specific http request should be canceled. We are trying to achive this be calling `.unsubscribe()` in our app.

Inside the web dev tools we can see that the request is marked as canceled, but the CancellationToken on our ASP.Net backend won't be set to `IsCancellationRequested = true`

Tests with postman works as expected and also after refreshing our swagger page after calling the request will set `IsCancellationRequested` to `true`

As i'm responsible only for the backend i don't know much about the frontend implementation. Please let me know if i should provide more information.

We are working with .net 6 and angular v13.

Does anyone have an idea, why the CancellationToken doesn't get canceled in this szenario. I already searched a lot, but no solution worked for us.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of code of the calling component ?

Comment: check any of given solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746297/how-to-cancel-net-core-web-api-request-using-angular) works for you ?

Comment: As i said, i'm not the developer of the frontend, but i will try to get a sample code. Meanwhile our frontenddev setup a dummy angular app and it seems like it is working as expected with that. So there must be an issue with our current app setup.