# Ignore cancelled tasks in exception handling middleware ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to avoid logging different types of cancelled requests, and I'm not sure what is the best practice here. I found in [GitHub post](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19526#issuecomment-989036617) wehre the developer is checking for different types this way:

```cs
private static bool IsCancellationException(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex == null) return false;
    if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
        return true;
    if (ex is System.IO.IOException && ex.Message == "The client reset the request stream.")
        return true;
    if (ex is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException)
        return true;
    // .NET SQL has a number of different exceptions thrown when operations are cancelled
    if (ex.Source == "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" && ex.Message == "Operation cancelled by user.")
        return true;
    if ((ex is Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException || ex is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) &&
        ex.Message.Contains("Operation cancelled by user"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But it seems really ugly to me so I came up with this:

```cs
// ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        HandleCancellationException(context, ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
    }
}
```

Wouldn't checking `context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested` be enough to ignore cancelled tasks?

From the docs I read that `IsCancellationRequested` only guarantees that cancellation was requested, so I guess it's possible that the task wasn't really cancelled and failed, but then would I really care since the client doesn't either?

This obviously doesn't handle the case where the task was cancelled by the server, but I actually want to see those in the logs, but not client initiated cancellations.

I could also handle `OperationCanceledException` but I think that's already covered by the first catch, so I probably don't need it and anyway I'm only interested in ignoring client cancellations.

What is the best practice here? Thank you!

BTW Using .NET 6

**UPDATE:**

I checked the default [ExceptionHandlerMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.cs) in ASP.NET Core and this is what they do:

```cs
if ((edi.SourceException is OperationCanceledException || edi.SourceException is IOException)
    && context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    _logger.RequestAbortedException();

    if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status499ClientClosedRequest;
    }

    return;
}
```

I could do the same, but would need to handle more types such as SqlException, and in some cases I need to check `ex.GetBaseException() is OperationCanceledException` because I noticed that for example `CsvWriter` library wraps the `OperationCanceledException` in a custom exception. I still think it's probably fine to catch Exception only, but not sure...

**UPDATE 2:**

I checked production logs, and interestingly I found `TaskCanceledException` entries where `IsCancellationRequested` was **false**, and I even managed to reproduce such a cancellation myself! It seems like it's not necessarily always even true even if the client cancelled the request...

It was really hard to reproduce though, but I got it to happen once. I noticed one differnce between these similar exceptions (except for the request being cancelled) was the existence of an `AsyncState` property (I'm writing all exception data as JSON). In any case, so far I've gone with this approach:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        HandleCancellationException(context, oce);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Ignore any cancellation-related exceptions by checking if request was cancelled
        HandleCancellationException(context, ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
    }
}
```

Perhaps it's better to ask the ASP.NET team on GitHub about this...

Comment: They "should" be equal so checking of one might be sufficient. But we are talking about a modular system were the relevant part might have been exchanged and, reading stuff here, there are always bugs like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153525/whats-the-difference-between-httpcontext-requestaborted-and-cancellationtoken-p). To be on the safe side check for both.

Comment: If I catch `OperationCanceledException` then tasks canceled by the server (if such can happen) would not be logged. I still don't see how adding that would help, unless I misunderstood your point?