# Kestrel + IIS Reverse Proxy RequestAborted Not Triggered

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

We have an ASP.NET Core 2.x Application that implements custom middleware that acts as a proxy in front of another (Java based) server/application. It is common for the clients of this application/middleware to frequently abort/cancel their request before the server request has completed.

We've deployed this application to IIS (as a reverse proxy) and running on Kestrel. [Prior to Core 2.x Kestrel had a bug that caused `HttpContext.RequestAborted` to always be `false`](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1139) (other related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574061/httprequest-not-aborted-cancelled-on-browser-abort-in-asp-net-core-mvc))...which was apparently fixed in 2.x (which I've been able to confirm).

However, it appears that when running IIS in front of Kestrel, it doesn't forward the request abort through to Kestrel and `RequestAborted` is **still** always `false`

Is there any way to get `RequestAborted` working in this configuration (or any other way to detect it if not)?

Simple reproduction repo: https://github.com/mikeomeara1/RequestAbortRepro

**UPDATE**

[This Comment](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1139#issuecomment-258281409) seems to indicate a known issue but it's largely unclear to what extent

[This Question](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/38) seems to also be related but again it's not completely apparent to me that it's directly related (at least it isn't spelled out in such terms).

@spender - If I understood you correctly, the header comparison is [here](https://gist.github.com/mikeomeara1/b2bf4f18099c8705471b7f895c7cc0fb). If not, let me know, I'll get you whatever you want to see.

It seems the tea leaves are indicating a known issue. So, the question is; Is there a way to work around this? We just went through (a very painful) 1.1 to 2.x upgrade in the hopes this issue would be addressed and letting our server thrash for another month/quarter/year has us pretty concerned at this point. The system we're working on is greatly scaling up in volume.

So, any workarounds, hacks or crazy ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you share the program and startup classes so that we can determine whether everything is correct in your code?

Comment: Can't share the program (it's huge) but this can be easily repro-ed using the default ASP.NET Core Template. Run it under IIS Express and cancel loading the page, RequestAborted = False. Run it under Kestrel, RequestAborted = True. I'll see about putting a repo up for it.

Comment: Is it possible that the aborts are undetectable? After all, if the client is pipelining (http1.1 reuse of the same underlying connection), then an aborted request is not necessarily an aborted connection. IMO there's a larger problem that might be addressed in another place if such a large number of users are bailing on the request/response.

Comment: It's a proxy against a mapping server which bails on requests after zoom/pan. Which can result in a huge number of canceled requests depending on how long it takes the server to render. I also (partially) understand the larger HTTP Protocol issue...but the fact of the matter is; it works as intended when using Kestrel alone...not when IIS is in front of it.

Comment: A comparison of request/response headers from the two different scenarios *might* yield something. I'd be interested in the `Connection` headers.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1139#issuecomment-258281409) makes me think like this won’t work with IIS.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too but was not exactly sure what it was in reference to and/or if it means I'm doa on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known issue and isn't fixed yet. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/38