# Can't cancel task in Asp.net core Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I am trying to cancel Task running in Asp.net Core Action.
For that I am using [this github](https://github.com/PawelGerr/aspnet-di) sample.
I can cancel task if running service in console, but if I run under IIS (or IIS Express) task is not canceling.
I saw similar issue [in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574061/httprequest-not-aborted-cancelled-on-browser-abort-in-asp-net-core-mvc). Based on it issue should be fixed already.
I am using .Net core 2.1.

Comment: Get clear what you mean with "cancel it"? Do you want to cancel the operation when the connection is lost (ie caller closed the connection or hit abort button in the browser)? Then pass `HttpContext.RequestAborted` to your async methods (its an cancellation token). If not how oyu intend user to cancel it?

Comment: I am aborting request from client using javascript or from WPF client calling Task.Cancel() and passing CancellationToken to service call

Comment: Did you try the above?  This is the way is supposed to work. It's an cancellation token

Comment: My issue is that HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested is false, but action is aborted from client

Comment: When I use Kestrel as server it is working, but when server is IIS it is not working

Comment: Did you try if its still an issue with ASP.NET Core 2.1 in process hosting?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/28/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-improvements-to-iis-hosting/

Comment: I will try later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I know this is known issue and doesn't fixed yet. [See more details](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/38) on ANCM project page.

Comment: I was hoping this is fixed after 2 years :)
Thanks for response.

Comment: Push MS team once more to be more productive :)

Comment: Same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110101/kestrel-iis-reverse-proxy-requestaborted-not-triggered . I asked the MS team about it as well...tumbleweeds.

Comment: :( we still need to fix this